# Как добавить запись в существующий XML-файл

Tags: xml, android, eclipse

Есть XML-файл, хочу добавить новые значения <data> в корень <root>
Как это сделать с помощью XMLSerializer в Android?   
Вот кусок кода который создает тэги:

```
            serializer.startTag(null, "data");
            serializer.text("yoba yo");
            serializer.startTag(null, "a");
            serializer.endTag(null, "a");
            serializer.endTag(null, "data");
            serializer.endDocument();
            serializer.flush();
            fileos.close();
```

Сам XML-файл такой:

```
<root>
<data>
    <a>yoba yo</a>
    <b>123</b>
</data>
<data>
    <a>yoba</a>
    <b>321</b>
</data>
>>>>>Сюда надо добавить новые <data>
</root>
```

Answer (score 3):

Всё что вы можете в таком случае сделать, это найти нужное место в файле, а потом открыть его на запись и пропустить (skip) нужное количество байт (как раз чтобы встать перед /root. А потом создать Writer и отдать его сериализатору.

Второй вариант (намного менее эффективный) это прочесть всё заново и записать, а потом дописать новое. Ясно что это приведёт к тому, что со временем добавление новых записей станет невозможной.

И третий вариант, который сам напрашивается в данной ситуации, это не использовать XML вообще. Ясно же, что он плохо подходит для этого. Используйте, например, [CSV](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSV) или придумайте сами какой-нибудь текстовый формат. Или сериализуйте просто через обычную сериализацию.

Comment: Подскажите где можно почитать про работу с CSV файлами?

Comment: Это просто текстовый формат.. просто пишите построчно разделяя поля табами.. и первая строка содержит названия столбцов.

Comment: Все приходит с опытом, поэтому лучше всего, как мне показалось, использовать DocumentBuilderFactory + DocumentBuilder + Document, а дальше уже создаем в документах Node, в них Element, ну и если надо то Attribute.